# mod_rewrite variable always == 'index.php'

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following file structure:

```
/framework
    /.htaccess
    /index.php
```

and the following rules in my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost/framework/example` I would expect the query string to equal 'framework/example' but instead it equals 'index.php'. Why? And how do I get the variable to equal when I'm expecting it to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rewrite rules are looping. Mod_rewrite won't stop rewriting until the URI (without the query string) is the same before and after it goes through the rules. When you originally request http://localhost/framework/example this is what happens:

1. Rewrite engine takes `/framework/example` and strips the leading "/"
2. `framework/example` is put through the rules
3. `framework/example` gets rewritten to `index.php?q=framework/example`
4. Rerite engine compares the before and after, `framework/example` != `index.php`
5. `index.php?q=framework/example` goes back through the rewrite rules
6. `index.php` gets rewritten to `index.php?q=index.php`
7. Rewrite engine compares the before and after, `index.php` == `index.php`
8. Rewrite engine stops, the resulting URI is `index.php?q=index.php`

You need to add a condition so that it won't rewrite the same URI twice:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've just tried adding that rule and the result is still the same.

Comment: Changing the RewriteCond regex to: !index\.php gets the desired result but then /framework/testing/index.php won't redirect (for obvious reasons)

Comment: @Peter Horne: use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` then. It is suitable in most cases

Comment: That's an improvement but I've just realised `RewriteCond $1 !^index\.php` solves the problem perfectly. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Because you've rewritten the url with `RewriteRule` and have already **put** the previous path to the `q`. So just use `$_GET['q']`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you expand on this please? There is no query string in the original request, so without the rules I've added then $_GET['q'] would be empty.

Comment: @Peter Horne: what can't you understand exactly? The original request is in GET's `q` variable, and to avoid infinity rewriting loop - follow the Jon Lin answer (which is correct and should work)

Comment: I misunderstood and thought you were talking about the incoming request (before it reaches my server) having ?q= already set! Thanks for your help.